# wordpress query can not search data with space?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have following code

```
$wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$device_token_table.' WHERE user_pushtoken="'.$server_method['user_pushtoken'].'"  AND user_id = '.$user_id,ARRAY_A );
print_r($wpdb->num_rows);
```

I run this query into MySql and it works and 1 row found but when I try this into wordpress then it is not working and 0 rows found.

Issue is spaces between `XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX`. I can not remove this spaces. I want to run this query into wordpress.

How can I run this query successfully?

Comment: i think quote is missing after '11,ARRAY_A...may be this is the reason.

Comment: I also add quote but did not work @ZafarMalik

Comment: It's seem you dont have the . between the ' and 11, try to see what is the generate sql like this `$sql='SELECT * FROM device_token_table WHERE user_pushtoken="XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX" AND user_id = '.11; var_dump($sql);`
And execute the SQL direct in MySQL and if all is fine change it for 
`$devide_token_data = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A );`

Comment: Please post the *actual query you are using*.  The one above is full of  typo issues, and will not run (it will throw an error - are you getting errors?)

Comment: @cale_b I was update my query

Comment: Great, thanks.  Now, can you echo the actual *query that is generated*? We see that you're including variables (you should check out `$wpdb->prepare`, by the way) - what does that query look like (actually) when it runs?  And, if you do a `var_dump($wpdb->last_error)` after you run it, do you get anything?